# String unicode with functions

Tags: unicode, ocaml, reason, bucklescript, unicode-literals

I am trying to archive that a function is returning a unicode string and I want to log it into the console. But it just either displays the information about the function or just not a unicode string.

```ml
let test = () => "ÜTEST"

Js.log(test());

Js.log({j|$test()|j});
```

The first one just returns `"ÃTEST"` and the second one just returns information about the function itself.

Here is a working example: https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=FAGwpgLgBBYM7QLxQBQEoqIHxQEQB2AVAUQGVDdhgApOAOhAHsBzFWBdNAbitoZZQBvAFYAfACTsI6UcIC+3IA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify that the string is unicode at the point of creation, not at the point of use:

```
let test = () => {j|ÜTEST|j}
Js.log(test());
```

Also, string interpolation, as in `{j|$test()|j}`, only works with simple variable substitution. `$test` will be replaced by the contents of `test`, which is a function. It will not yield the result of calling `test`.

For more details, see the section on [Unicode Support & Interpolation](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/common-data-types#string) in the BuckleScript manual.